# How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

With a contenteditable element how can I replace the selected content with my own html?

Comment: The second part of this question (“replace selected text with html of my own”) is not answered in he question linked as a reference for this one being a duplicate.

Comment: I removed the already answered part to comply with the "one question per question" rule.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3997659/104380

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**See here for working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKaJ3/2/**

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    alert(html);
}
```

Code taken from [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down): [Return HTML from a user-selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652734/return-html-from-a-user-selection/4652824#4652824)

Comment: BTW - Never call the function `getSelection()`, as this will override the default and cause stack recursion

Comment: works great! thanks.  how would I now replace the selected text with something else in same position as the text is?

Comment: nevermind, found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997659/replace-selected-text-in-contenteditable-div?rq=1

Comment: Nice, But one more question please, it return the selected text from whole document, how can get only a selected div. May be a div with a distinct class?

Comment: It's not solving the problem: how would you replace the selection, if there are at least two similar strings?

Answer (score 54):

To get the selected HTML, you can use the function I wrote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652734/return-html-from-a-user-selection/4652824#4652824). To replace the selection with your own HTML, you can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362747/how-to-insert-an-element-at-selected-position-in-html-document/3363087#3363087). Here's a version of the replacer function that inserts an HTML string instead of a DOM node:

```
function replaceSelectionWithHtml(html) {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), child;
        while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
            frag.appendChild(child);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
}

replaceSelectionWithHtml("<b>REPLACEMENT HTML</b>");
```

Comment: Please define `node`.  I think we can just delete this line `html = (node.nodeType == 3) ? node.data : node.outerHTML;`

Comment: @HDog: Yes, you're right. Looks like a copy-pasted line I forgot to remove. I've deleted it now. Thanks.

Comment: Why is 'html' both a parameter to the function and a local variable declaration? It works because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27963351/578812 but it seems confusing at first glance.

Comment: @CraigA: It's a mistake. I suspect I copied and adapted a function that didn't have the `html` parameter. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Wonderful answer! But there's one thing I don't get, why is this valid syntax: `var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), child;` . Why doesn't the comma raise an error? I'd be very grateful if you could explain how this statement works

Comment: @flen: The `var` statement in JavaScript allows you to declare multiple variables in a single statement, separated by comma, each variable optionally having an initial value. [More info at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: @TimDown Thanks a lot! Now I got it, `child` is just a variable declaration, without any assingment. Just like `var frag = 42; var child;`

Comment: @TimDown, I've used this on a ContentEditable div. But it seems you can Undo/Redo anything inserted via this snippet. Is there any way to do it so Undo/Redo captures it? Thanks

Comment: @XahedKamal: I don't think so. I believe that changes made by using [`document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) go onto the browser undo stack but there's no command that gives you precise control over what HTML is inserted and how it's inserted.