# Is user selection a child element using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I detect if a user selection (highlighting with mouse) is within/a child of a certain element?

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
   sdfsdf
   <div id="container">
       some 
      <span>content</span>
   </div>
   sdfsd
</div>
```

pseudo code:

```
if the entire range of window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) is within/a child of #container
 return true;
else
 return false;
```

Update:
I think this can be done by looking at each of the parent elements of the most top element in the range and see if there's a match with #container. I just need help writing this in JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect user selection within html element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809682/detect-user-selection-within-html-element)

Comment: im asking for the entire range in this question