# how to get html text covered by other div

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, z-index

Here's the thing. I can get selected text with that solution: [How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac)

But now i have a problem. I'm adding to website divs with different colors to mark some parts of page (i'm setting just position=absolute, top, left, width, height, backgroundColor and opacity) and now when i want to select marked text, selected is that div (which i guess have higher z-index or something else is placing it over other html). And now when i want to get selected text i'm getting nothing. Not even that div. Just null... Any idea how can i get text covered by that div?

And all these things i'm doing in UIWebView component in iOS but that's not relevant, i think.

Comment: You might try adding the css definition `pointer-events:none;` to the divs that overlay your content.

Comment: But note that this isn't supported in IE or Opera. (except in SVG)

Comment: i need it for iPads and iPhone's so i don't care about IE and Opera. Thanks a lot!