# WYSIWYG in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, wysiwyg

I have a problem with my WYSIWYG-Editor, it works in FF but not in Chrome :(

Here's the code:

```
    $.fn.textEdit = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this), $div = $('<div class="textEdit"></div>');

                var $buttonObserve = function(cmd,b,val){

                    document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', 0, false);
                    document.execCommand(cmd, b||false, val||null);

                };
                $this.before($div);
                $this.attr({contentEditable:true})

                $($div).append(
                        $('<div/>').addClass('textEditBold').text('F').attr('title','Fett')
                            .click(function(){ $buttonObserve('bold') })
                    ).append(
                        $('<div/>').addClass('textEditItalics').text('K').attr('title','Kursiv')
                            .click(function(){ $buttonObserve('italic') })
                    ).append(
                        $('<div/>').addClass('textEditUnderline transparent').text('_').attr('title','Unterstrich').css('background', 'url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKECAAAAAF9vj////////yH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAWABYAAAIrlI+py+0Po5zUgAsEzvEeL4Ea15EiJJ5PSqJmuwKBEKgxVuXWtun+DwxCCgA7) no-repeat 0 1px')
                            .click(function(){ $buttonObserve('underline') })
                    ).append(
                        $('<div/>').addClass('delete').text('Deactivate-Edit').attr('title','Stop-Edit')
                            .click(function(){  $this.parents('#page2').find('.editable').removeClass('editable').removeAttr('contentEditable');
                                                $this.parents('#page2').find('.textEdit').remove('.textEdit'); })
                );

        });



};
```

This function get activated if the user click on an p, div elemt and so on, it will create 4 buttons, for make the text: Bold, italic, underlined, oder delete the buttons.

The Problem is: If i select the text and press a button, nothing happens, just the delete button works.

I think Chrome doesn't accept my selected text.

I hope u guys can help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `execCommand()` support has been removed from Webkit.
[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html) doesn't even list the later browsers in the support matrix.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/QytGD5gCREY

To get the selected text you could follow this method

[How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac)