# Text Selection using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a div container placed inside an html page. There is some text placed inside it. Now, I want the text (any amount) selected by the user  to be displayed in another div container on the same page.

```
<div id="d1"> Some Random text, Some Random text Some Random text, Some Random text</div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

I am stuck on how to extract the text from the `d1` container. I have tried using `window.getSelection()` and related methods. The irony is that it is applied on the entire document. How to go about it?

P.S-JSFiddle demo would be helpful.

Comment: P.P.S. A JSFiddle of what you've tried would be even more helpful

Comment: have a look at this http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it. But, they have used methods (that are defined on the document object of JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getSelection ) that apply on the entire document. I just want to restrict it to the the div content only and not the entire page.

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click is not working well on double-clicking or clicking the text. It works only when the user gently presses the left mouse button and selects some content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this on my mac seems to be working on Safari/Chrome and FF not sure about IE though

```
<head>
    <script>
        var mouseup_fun = function()
        {
            var str = document.getSelection().toString();
            if (str.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = str;  
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="div1" onmouseup="mouseup_fun()">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    </br></br>
    <div id="div2">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The above answer is working well. Love Stack Overflow Community :)