# Getting the selected text from a table in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in which I can get the selected text in a table using jquery after _mouseStop?

```
<table id='grid' class='TableStyle'>

    <tr>
        <td class='cellGrid'>F</td>                                                                      
        <td class='cellGrid'>W</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class='cellGrid'>F</td>                                                                      
        <td class='cellGrid'>W</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

When the text is highlighted, the class of that `td`, is changed to `cellHighlight`.

I think that I need to loop in the table grid and find those that their class is `cellHighlight` and then use `.text()` to get the value?

Am I right? If yes, is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You need only one Clicked cell text or multiple cells which are highlighted? and what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var txt = $("#grid .cellHighlight").text()
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's only one (1) that can be highlighted at a time then you can do

```
var hightlightedText = $('table#grid td.cellHighlight').text();
console.log(hightlightedText);
```

However if you have multiple cases:

```
var cells = $('#grid .cellHighlight');
var texts = []
$.each(cells, function(index){
    texts.push($(cells[index]).text());
});
console.log(texts);
>> ["W", "F"]
```

[An example JsFiddle found here](http://jsfiddle.net/R2H5n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If all that you wanted was to get the selectedText anywhere on your page. you should do this.

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    alert( text);
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Qr9G/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found something interesting just what you want, may be something like this:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    alert(html);
}
```

This is answered by Alison on this post [**How to get selected(user-highlighted) text in contenteditable element and replace it?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#grid .cellGrid").mouseup( function(){    
    alert($(this).html());
});
```