# Highlight the text and count characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This might be a rather silly question. But how do you highlight or select any text or p tag in the body and jQuery will count the selected/highlighted characters?
Thanks

I've got this, but getting 0

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('p').mouseup(function(){

        var length = $(this).val().length;

        console.log(length);

    });

});
</script>
```

P.S. For those who voting down. Why do you do that? Should not we be helping each other?!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: You mean the user highlighted text? You might be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac

Comment: yes, when user highlights or selects the text with the mouse then count the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JsFiddle Link shows up selected text for  `all html tags below`

http://jsfiddle.net/zKnFs/1/

```
<input id="inp" value="Hello world!"/>
<textarea id="txtarea">Hello world!</textarea>
<p id="para"> This is a paragraph</p>
<span id="spa"> This is a span</span>
<label id="lbl"> This is a label</label>
```

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

$('.paragraphCount').html('Paragraph count is '+$('p').addClass('highlight').length);

Comment: Cool, the thing is that I know how to count the value or characters it is just that what (mouse) event I meant to be using to do that? So when you live select a certain text then console will fire the total length of selected text