# multiple seperate area selection in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to coding, and have been making a Text Editor component using the textarea: https://jsfiddle.net/chrismg12/jLk70ar3/5/

I was going to make a function that's selects all instances of a found word. However I don't know how to do so in a textarea.NOTE:This is not about multiple carets, but rather multiple selection, however advice in implementations of multiple carets would be heavily appreciated.
HTML

```js
var lNo = "";

function injectStyles(rule) {
  var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '&shy;<style>' + rule + '</style>'
  }).appendTo("body");
}

$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (typeof end == "undefined") {
      end = start;
    }
    if (start == -1) {
      start = this.value.length;
    }
    if (end == -1) {
      end = this.value.length;
    }
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
      this.focus();
      this.setSelectionRange(start, end + 1);
    } else if (this.createTextRange) {
      var range = this.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', end);
      range.moveStart('character', start);
      range.select();
    }
  });
};

$.fn.selectRangeExcludingLast = function(start, end) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (typeof end == "undefined") {
      end = start;
    }
    if (start == -1) {
      start = this.value.length;
    }
    if (end == -1) {
      end = this.value.length;
    }
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
      this.focus();
      this.setSelectionRange(start, end + 1);
    } else if (this.createTextRange) {
      var range = this.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', end);
      range.moveStart('character', start);
      range.select();
    }
  });
};

function getPos(str, substr, index) {
  var io = str.split(substr, index).join(substr).length;
  if (io >= str.length) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return io;
  }
}

function gutterChildControl(gutter, textarea, settings) {
  if (gutter.childNodes.length != $(textarea).val().split("\n").length) {
    while (gutter.childNodes.length < $(textarea).val().split("\n").length) {
      var gutterChild = document.createElement("div");
      gutterChild.className = "gutterChild"
      gutterChild.style.height = $(textarea).css('line-height');
      var gutterChildLineHeight = $(textarea).css('line-height');
      $(gutterChild).css('line-height', gutterChildLineHeight)
      gutterChild.style.fontSize = $(textarea).css('font-size');
      gutterChild.style.width = "100%";
      gutterChild.style.color = settings.gFontCol;
      gutterChild.style.paddingRight = `${settings.gPadding}px`;
      gutterChild.style.paddingLeft = `${settings.gPadding}px`;
      gutterChild.style.textAlign = settings.gFontAlign;
      gutterChild.onmouseover = function() {
        gutterChild.style.opacity = "0.75"
      }
      gutterChild.onmouseleave = function() {
        gutterChild.style.opacity = "1"
      }
      gutterChild.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(gutterChild.innerHTML) != 1) {
          startPos = getPos($(textarea).val(), "\n", parseInt(gutterChild.innerHTML) - 1)
          console.log(`startPos:${startPos}`);
          endPos = getPos($(textarea).val(), "\n", parseInt(gutterChild.innerHTML))
          if (endPos == -1) {
            endPos = $(textarea).val().length - 1
          }
          console.log(`endPos:${endPos}`)
          $(textarea).selectRange(startPos, endPos);
        } else {
          startPos = 0;
          console.log(`startPos:${startPos}`)
          endPos = getPos($(textarea).val(), "\n", 1)
          if (endPos == -1) {
            endPos = $(textarea).val().length - 1
            if (endPos == -1) {
              endPos = 0;
            }
          }
          console.log(`endPos:${endPos}`)
          $(textarea).selectRange(startPos, endPos);
        }
      }

      gutter.appendChild(gutterChild);
      gutterChild.innerHTML = `${gutter.childNodes.length}`
    }
    while (gutter.childNodes.length > $(textarea).val().split("\n").length) {
      gutter.removeChild(gutter.lastChild)
    }
    // while(gutter.childNodes.length > $(textarea).val().split("\n").length){
    //  gutter.childNodes.pop;
    // }
  }
}

function Ventify(element, options) {
  const settings = {
    taCol: "#1d252c",
    gCol: "#1d252c",
    fSize: "22px",
    gFontCol: "rgba(58,74,88,1)",
    pad: 1,
    gFontAlign: "center",
    gPadding: 20,
    ...options
  }
  element.style.display = "flex";
  element.style.flexDirection = "row";
  var gutter = document.createElement("div");
  var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  gutter.className = "gutter";
  gutter.classList.add("scrll")
  textarea.className = "ventiEditor";
  textarea.classList.add("scrll")

  gutter.style.width = "100px";
  gutter.style.height = "100%";
  gutter.style.backgroundColor = settings.gCol;
  gutter.style.overflowY = "scroll"
  gutter.style.scrollbarWidth = "none";
  injectStyles(".gutter::-webkit-scrollbar{width:0px;}")
  injectStyles(".ventiEditor{outline:0px !important;-webkit-appearance:none;}")

  textarea.style.width = "calc(100% - 100px)";
  textarea.style.fontSize = settings.fSize;
  textarea.style.color = settings.gFontCol;
  textarea.style.overflowY = "scroll";
  textarea.style.whiteSpace = "pre";
  textarea.style.resize = "none";
  textarea.style.height = "100%";
  textarea.style.margin = "0px 0px 0px 0px"
  textarea.style.border = "0px solid rgb(255,255,255)"
  textarea.style.padding = "0"
  $(textarea).css('line-height', `calc(${2*settings.pad}px + ${settings.fSize})`)
  textarea.style.backgroundColor = settings.taCol;
  textarea.spellcheck = false;
  $(textarea).css("-moz-tab-size", "4");
  $(textarea).css("tab-size", "4")
  $('.ventiEditor:focus').css('outline', '0px !important')
  $('.ventiEditor:focus').css('-webkit-appearance', 'none')
  textarea.oninput = function() {
    var gutter = textarea.parentElement.childNodes[0];
    gutterChildControl(gutter, textarea, settings)
  };
  textarea.onscroll = function() {
    gutter.scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop
  }
  $(textarea).keydown(function(e1) {
    if (e1.ctrlKey) {
      if (e1.keyCode >= 48 && e1.keyCode <= 57) {
        lNo += e1.key;
        console.log(lNo);
      }
    }
  })
  // gutter.onscroll = function(){
  //  if(gutter.scrollTop != textarea.scrollTop){
  //      textarea.scrollTop = gutter.scrollTop;
  //  }
  // }
  element.appendChild(gutter);
  element.appendChild(textarea);
  gutterChildControl(gutter, textarea, settings);
}

function gutterFix(textarea) {}

$(document).delegate('.ventiEditor', 'keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd;

    // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start) +
      "\t" +
      $(this).val().substring(end));

    // put caret at right position again
    this.selectionStart =
      this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
});

injectStyles(".gutterChild{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}")
Ventify(document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0], {
  taCol: "#1d252c",
  gCol: "#1d252c",
  pad: 5,
  gFontCol: '#bbb'
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Browsers can only handle a single text selection.

Comment: checkout my answer which is similar to tthis question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946573/save-selection-text-and-show-it-later-in-html-and-javascript/48240790#48240790

Comment: The above is one solution, but doesn't work with a `textarea`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up an empty array and push the positions of all the matching strings to it. (E.g If you're looking for '`this`' in the string '`this and this match; so does this`', your array would get [0,9,29].) You might want/need to use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

With this information (and knowing the length of the substring), you can do something like:
 - overlaying a div on the textarea (maybe with [contenteditable="true"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) and `z-index: 1`)
 - enclosing each of the matching strings in a span element (more info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span)) and maybe giving all these spans a class,
 - using querySelectorAll to get a NodeList including all of these spans, and
 - looping through the list to change their style (so the
   user can see what is "selected") and their contents (assuming the point was
   for the user to be able to make changes.)

You can remove the wrapping spans later, update the text area with the updated text, and remove the overlaid div.
Note that your array of indexes probably won't stay valid for long, and depending what you're doing with the initial list, you may want to loop through it backwards to protect these values until you no longer need them.

That's my brainstorming anyway.

Comment: Seems like it will work, trying on it rn, will notify after my trials.