# Select a text, put it in bold and save the position of the bold tags to surround these same texts later

Tags: javascript, dom, range

*I edited my problem because it was not explained enough*

My goal is to let the user selects some texts in a specific div, make these texts bold and save the *boundaries* of theses selections to retrieve them later. That way, we can imagine (for example) that when the user comes back later on this page and that this div is loaded, his bolded texts are here.

That's why I need to save some data to retrieve the "positions" of the  tags to surround back the selected texts. But I don't know what to save exactly nor how.

Here is the scenario. Let's say we have this div somewhere in the document:

```html
<div id="unique">
  <p>My text is awesome !</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      Here is an other text interesting too.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The user makes two selections so I use basically

```
var selection = window.getSelection()
```

I have extra code to limit the selection etc... but it's not important here. At the end I retrieve a Range object which is based on this code

```
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
```

To put the text in bold, I use:

```
range.surroundContents(document.createElement("b"));
```

And it works, each time the user selects something, the bold tag is inserted in the DOM like this:

```html
<div id="unique">
  <p>My <b>text is awesome</b> !</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      Here is <b>an other text</b> interesting too.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

So now my question is: how can I "save" the exact "positions" of the bold tags relative to the div with id "unique", to load them later (load means here surround again with the  tag). More precisely my question is about what data I need to save ?

I tried to store the Range objects, but they are evolving because each time I surround a text with the bold tags, DOM is affected so are the Range objects too.

At the end with a function like this, I'd like to be able to put the text back in bold

```
loadBolds() {
  //boldRanges is an array containing the ranges of the selections

  boldRanges.forEach((range) => {
    range.surroundContents(document.createElement("bold"))
  });
}
```

I hope it's clear now !

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried here? Please post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a set of functions to work through the nodes, saving the results in some organized way and saving that.

```js
function hasBold(n) {
  return !!n.getElementsByTagName && !!n.getElementsByTagName('b').length;
}

function boldText(n) {
  return (n.nodeName == "B") ? n.textContent : "";
}

function boldCount(n) {
  return !!n.getElementsByTagName ? n.getElementsByTagName('b').length : 0;
}

function indexInSiblings(n) {
  var i = 0;
  while ((n = n.previousSibling) != null)
    i++;
  return i;
}

function checkNode(n, t = "B") {
  return {
    is: n.nodeName == "B",
    name: n.nodeName,
    text: boldText(n),
    has: hasBold(n),
    count: boldCount(n)
  };
}
const container = document.getElementById('unique');
let c = checkNode(container);
console.log(c);
var nodeList = container.childNodes;//5
var nodeC = container.children;//2
console.log("nodeList,nodeC:",nodeList.length,nodeC.length);
console.log("nodeName:1,1", nodeList[1].childNodes[1].nodeName);
console.log("nodeName:0", nodeList[0].nodeName);

let nodeN = 1;
let me = nodeList[nodeN].childNodes[1];
console.log("nodeList:" + nodeN, me.nodeName, checkNode(me));
```

```html
<div id="unique">
  <p>My <b>text is awesome</b> !</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      Here is <b>an other text</b> interesting too.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar problem there, I think it will solve mine

[Save selection text and show it later in html and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946573/save-selection-text-and-show-it-later-in-html-and-javascript)