# webview javascript not running in all android devices

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I have a problem that not all javascript methods run on webview on different android devices, it is running perfectly on browser (firefox, chrome and internet explorer) but not running in webview of some android devices

like this method in the following post :

[How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac)

it is running on s3 but not working in tablet for example

can any one tell me what is the problem and how can I be able to make javascript method that can run on all android os

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ymmv, but I noticed some (older) devices did not run javascript if the `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` method was called after `WebView.loadData`