# How to get the selected text in page using jquery dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, selection

I'm trying to get the text which we select in the page.I'm displaying the data dynamically on the page.

Code:

```
//get selection 
var getSelected = function () {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
};

$("#text").select(function (eventObject) {
    console.log(getSelected().toString());
});
```

The data in the page contains in

```
chapterHTML += '<p id="text"><sup>'+ (i+1) +'</sup>'+ vers.text() +'</p>';
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac

Comment: @RohanKumar yes but i'm not getting the actual selected text in page

Comment: Can you create a live demo for it like on **fiddle** or use `contenteditable='true'` on your `element`

Comment: If you open "Genisis" then some text is displaying i want to get that data

Comment: @RohanKumar i solve my solution Thank you for your valuable responses :)