# Selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get selection of block of text (including div's and formatting), I have function 'text_redesign' that should do it and I call it onlick to some button. But it select only the place in button where I clicked, i.e. on button is written "Restructure" and if I click close to 'R', I will get "R span class="someclass_tigran" /span estructure", and if I click close to 't', than I get "Restruc span class="someclass_tigran"/span ture". So it gets the place where I clicked, but not the selected text.

```
function text_redesign()
{
    var text_comonent_area = $("#text_block_1").contents().find('iframe'); //.contents();
    //var len = text_comonent_area.value.length;
    //var start = text_comonent_area.selectionStart;
    //var end = text_comonent_area.selectionEnd;
    //var sel = text_comonent_area.value.substring(start, end);
    //console.log("start " + start + " end " + end);
    var selObj = window.getSelection()
    console.log(selObj);
    var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    console.log(selRange);
    if(selObj.getRangeAt){ // thats for FF
        console.log("sdfsdf33");
        var range = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
        var newNode = document.createElement("span");
        newNode.setAttribute('class', 'someclass_tigran');
        range.surroundContents(newNode);
    }

}
```

P.S. I want apply it to iframe, but I tried as inside frame and well as to document and the result is same.
I am new to selection, so if you know where my mistake can be, please, tell and I will google it. Now I have no idea what to search for.

Comment: Not sure i understand your issue. Could you provide relevant HTML markup too? If you select some text in a DIV and then click a button, you loose selection. So what is expected behaviour?

Comment: Expected: selected area (inc. div's and formatiing) will be surronded by span. No, I do not lose selection. It remain, but funtion select button instead.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I loose selection.

<div class="button_top" title="" onclick="text_redesign();">Restructure</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be better to check the selected text in text_redesign function.

Look at this example:
[How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac)

Comment: The problem was that area was diselected when I pressed the button.