# how to find selected text in html

Tags: javascript, html, text, selection

how i can to find selected text in a `div` , in `html`

for example we have selected from 5 to 11 in this text :

```
     <div id="txt" >This is some <i> text </i> </div>
```

selected : `is some`  ,

but in `html` is : `id="txt`

how to find this and replace between `<p>` or `<span>` that other tags to avoid loss of ?

excuse me for my bad english :)

Comment: Please add the code producing `id="txt`.

Comment: this isn't a code . its just selected from 5 to 11 in html ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dKaJ3/2/

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    alert(html);
}
```

Taken from: [How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac)

Try to find things before you ask ;]