# jQuery / javascript split text node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split, textnode

i need to split an HTML element based on a users selection like this :

```
<p> Hi , i need to <b>split <i> an  [HTML] element </i> based on a users selection </b></p>
```

in first use :

```
<p> Hi , i need to <b>split <i> an </i> HTML <i> element </i> based on a users selection </b></p>
```

and in 2nd use :

```
 <p> Hi , i need to <b>split <i> an </i></b></p>
  HTML 
 <p><b><i> element </i> based on a users selection </b></p>
```

i have `getSelectionHtml()` , `replaceSelectionWithHtml(html)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-replace-selected-text-with-html-in-a-contenteditable-element) .

also :

```
function range(){
   var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

   var a = range.startContainer ;
    els = [];
    while (a.tagName != 'DIV') {
       els.unshift(a);
       a = a.parentNode;
    }
}
//so i have els[0] = <p> element , els[1] = <b> element , els[2] = <i> element
```

please help .

Comment: please do clearly ask the question.

Comment: Are you trying to create an editor?

Comment: + Anoop Joshi  yeah :)

Comment: +C-link Nepal : where is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want replace the particular string. You can try this.

```
("<p> Hi , i need to <b>split <i> an  [HTML] element </i> based on a users selection </b></p>").replace(/[HTML]/g, '</i> HTML <i> ')
```

Comment: thank you but indeed i want to learn working with nodes and elements.

Comment: and `[HTML]` means that (HTML) characters was selected with mouse

Comment: so you want to replace the html tags the user clicks on?