# Why is the function argument not overwritten on creating variable of same name inside the function?

Tags: javascript, variables, function-parameter

```
var a = 'why is this not undefined?';
function checkScope(a) {
    var a;
    console.log(a);
}
checkScope(a);
```

Javascript is functional scope language, right? When I declare a new variable just inside the function that uses the same name as the functional argument, why does the newly defined variable still hold the same data as the argument?

I thought it should be undefined?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that, because of hoisting, both `a` vars are declared before you call the function, so the parameter `a` becomes the same var as the declared `a` inside the function.

Comment: What is "*functional scope*"? JS has function scope, i.e. parameter names, function and variable declarations define variable names for the whole function body. There is nothing overwriting each other here.

Comment: JS syntax allows this!?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`var a;` is actually a variable *declaration* statement. When the function is defined, all the variables declared in it, are processed before the code execution and so you can use the variables even before the actual declaration line is executed at runtime. This is called [`var` hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). So, no matter how many times you declare a variable, the variable is actually declared only once.

In your case, you have defined `a` as one of the parameters to the function, which is scoped to the current function. And then you are declaring a variable with the same name. Since `a` is already declared in the function, as one of the parameters, the `var a;` declaration will be ignored.

That is why you are getting `why is this not undefined?` in the console.

Instead of `var a;`, lets say you had `var a = 1;`, in this case, the variable is already declared but *the assignment expression will be evaluated at runtime* and the value `1` will be assigned to `a`. So, the `console.log` will print `1`.

---

This behaviour is explained in the ECMA Script 5.1 Specification, under the section [10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5),

> 4. If *code* is function code, then
>
>    a. Let func be the function whose [[Call]] internal method initiated execution of *code*. Let *names* be the value of *func*’s
>      [[FormalParameters]] internal property.
>
>    b. Let *argCount* be the number of elements in args.
>
>    c. Let *n* be the number 0.
>
>    d. For each String *argName* in *names*, in list order do
>
>    i. Let *n* be the current value of *n* plus 1.
>
>    ii. If *n* is greater than *argCount*, let *v* be undefined otherwise let *v* be the value of the *n*’th element of *args*.
>
>    iii. **Let *argAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env*’s HasBinding concrete method passing *argName* as the argument.**
>
>    iv. **If *argAlreadyDeclared* is false, call *env*’s CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *argName* as the
>      argument.**
>
>    v. Call *env*’s SetMutableBinding concrete method passing *argName*, *v*, and *strict* as the arguments.

....

> 8. For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn d* in *code*, in source text order do
>
>    a. Let *dn* be the *Identifier* in *d*.
>
>    b. Let *varAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env*’s HasBinding concrete method passing *dn* as the argument.
>
>    c. **If *varAlreadyDeclared* is false, then**
>
>    i. **Call *env*’s CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and *configurableBindings* as the arguments.**
>
>    ii. Call *env*’s SetMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn*, undefined, and *strict* as the arguments.

As we see in the specification, the arguments and the variables declared in the function, all are actually defined in the execution environment corresponding to the function in which they are defined. So, if the arguments and the variables have the same name, the variable is actually defined only once and the second declaration is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

1. you are passing the variable a to the function check as a parameter.`function checkScope(a) {`
2. inside the function you are again trying to declare var a,  `var a;`

Both of these are within the same scope, right? i.e both inside the function check();

And according to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), that `var a` inside the function is same variable which you passed as parameter and you are just using it before declaration... you can do it with JS

So the code you have written is equuivalent to

```
var a = 'why is this not undefined?';
function checkScope(a) {

    console.log(a);
}
checkScope(a);
```

i.e the var a is just ignored.

And what you expect that var a should return undefined then the code would be like this

```
var a = 'why is this not undefined?';
function checkScope() {
   var a
    console.log(a);
}
checkScope();
```

This time we are not passing the parameter a to the function and a new variable `var a` is created within the function scope, thus becomes undefined

Answer (score 4):

The parameter is still defined inside the function, becase the `var a;` is ignored when the variable is already defined inside the same scope.

A statement like `var a;` doesn't mean that the variable is created at that point in the code. All variable declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the scope, so you can redeclare them as many times you want in the scope, and they are still only created once.

If a declaration has an assignment though, like `var a = 2;`, the assignment happens where the statement is in the code, regardless if the declaration is ignored or not.

Example:

```js
function check(a) {
  // both a and b exist here
  document.write('a = ' + a + ', b = ' + b + '<br>');
  var b = 1;
  document.write('a = ' + a + ', b = ' + b + '<br>');
  var a = 2; // not recreated, but assigned
  document.write('a = ' + a + ', b = ' + b + '<br>');
}

check(42);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because JavaScript ignores redeclarations of variables. However, if you had this instead:

```
var a = 'why is this not undefined?';
function checkScope(a) {
    var a = 'foo';
    console.log(a);
}
checkScope(a);
```

The value of `a` would be overwritten. Because `var a = 'foo';` is composed by a variable declaration (`var a;`) and a value assignment (`a = 'foo';`);

This behaviour is described in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).