# Javascript undefined in the end of row

Tags: javascript

```js
function addS(b){
   var b;
    for(i=1;i<b+1;i++){
        console.log((i-1)+" + "+ i +" = " + ((i-1)+i));
    }
}
console.log(addS(15));
```

It gives me UNDEFINED in the last row how do I take it off

Comment: Try returning something?

Comment: `b` is declared twice

Comment: @sebnukem [It doesn't matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963214/why-is-the-function-argument-not-overwritten-on-creating-variable-of-same-name-i)

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything.

Instead of doing `console.log` on the last line, just do `addS`:

```
addS(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(addS(15));
```

runs your function `addS()` (which logs something in your case) **and** then logs the result of this function again.

As you this function doesn't return anything (because you don't have a `return` statement in this function), the result is `undefined`.

Using just `addS(15)` would solve this problem.