# Add text and html unicode characters to a textarea element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode, utf-8

I have textarea that I am using to add text and emojis when a user types. To get the smileys to work I have images that users can click or use the default on a users device keyboard. 
At the moment I can type in the box or use the emjois, I cant do both.

To get the unicode for the characters I have to add the unicode string to the textarea like:

```
var t = $('#msgWriteArea').html() + '&#x'+ code;
$('#msgWriteArea').html(t);
```

The problem I am having is when I type in the box before or after I insert these the text is accessible through the `.val()` or value attribute and the Unicode characters are accessible through the `.html()` or `innerHtml` attribute.

Is there a way I can input text into a textarea as HTML instead of as a value or is there a way I can combine unicode characters and text in the same textarea.

> [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opjaeLpp/1/) of the problem

Managed to fix the problem, there was quite a few things to change most importantly changing textarea to 
That made things a lot easier

Heres a fiddle,

> [FIXED VERSION](https://jsfiddle.net/opjaeLpp/2/)

Cant take all the credit, the answers for these questions helped

[Insert text into textarea with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery/946556#946556)

[Get caret position in contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div)

[How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)

[How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-replace-selected-text-with-html-in-a-contenteditable-element)

Its not the neatest coding and probably could be done better, feel free to edit the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opjaeLpp/2/) make it better if you can it may help others who are stuck in the same place

Answer (score 4):

Recently I had the same problem and wanted to stay with textarea and pure javascript. 
The solution is to pre-render an emoticon in a temporary div and replace the textarea value together with the rendered HTML

```
let msg = document.getElementById('textareaID').value;
let g = document.createElement('div');
g.innerHTML = '&#x1f609';
let z = g.innerHTML;

document.getElementById('textareaID').value = msg + '' + z;

delete(g);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is a bit older, I would like to add an alternative solution **without** changing the original html.

Beause the main problem is that the proposed solution involves changing a textarea into a contenteditable-container. While this works nicely at first sight, downside of this approach is that you need a workaround for the placeholder attribute, accessibility problems (as it is not a 'proper' input), and tabbing issues.

With a slight rewrite you can still use the textarea, combined with the val([...]) function, and the emojis written as surrogate pairs:

```
    $('textarea').val($('textarea').val() + ' ' + emoticon);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ay03mh6z/

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with unicode in javascript, use `\u0000` instead of `&#x0000`.

You might also want to insert the characters at the caret... I recently created a userscript that does this same thing for GitHub comments (you might want to check out the code) - [GitHub Custom Emojis](https://github.com/StylishThemes/GitHub-Custom-Emojis). It uses [At.js](https://github.com/ichord/At.js/) to add an autocomplete dropdown which takes care of the insertion of text at the caret for you.

---

Update: Using a contenteditable div is a better way to go as it allows you to insert the image ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/opjaeLpp/3/)). The problem now is that the code is using `.html()` to add the content. Instead, it will need to be changed to use something like [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/) to insert the HTML at the caret or replace user selected text. You'll see the problem in the demo I linked in this update once an image is inserted and more text is added (`text <img> text`).

Comment: I tried swapping the line to use the unicode \u0000 but i get an illegal TOKEN error on that line, if i double \\ the unicode (\\u0000) it inserts but as text instead of the charactor

Comment: also the same problem, i can have text or unicode I cant combine them both

Comment: Added a link to the question for a basic version. The problem is there but theres just no styling to it

Comment: There is no styling because 1) it is a unicode character,  2) if the OS doesn't automatically replace it, you'll need something like the [Emoji One Chrome extension](http://emojione.com/chrome/) to do that for you and lastly, 3) It's a textarea, you can't replace a unicode character with an image because the textarea will show the HTML instead of the image.

Comment: I met CSS the page is more styled than that

Comment: Fixed it but JSFiddle, could tool for working on js functions thanks