# insert current element before previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm checking to see if element is last in the container div by getting length on next element with class `.item` (if there is such element, it means that I am currently not at the end of the container div)

```
if($(this).next('.item').length < 1) {
  console.log('element is last');
}
```

In case if it is last, I want to move it up, i.e insert it before previous `.item` so it now becomes second last.

I looked into `.insertBefore()` , however I don't explicitly know which "before" element to target.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362747/how-to-insert-an-element-at-selected-position-in-html-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:last` selector to get the last element in a matched set. From there you can use `insertBefore()` and `prev()` to move it as required. Try this:

```
var $last = $('.item:last');
$last.insertBefore($last.prev());
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0z5yhmcv/)