# CSS/JS/HTML - Highlight user selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write some code to let the user highlight parts of a website's content. To do so, I replace the user selection (`selectedText`) by some HTML (`<div class = "highlight">selectedText</div>`) - and it works (*cf*. code below).

The problem is that wrapping the selected text in this way overrides the rest of the CSS and ruins the layout, regardless of the HTML tag used as a container (div, span, em, mark, hr, ...). 
I apologize if the solution to this problem is obvious, I'm quite new to web dev.

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  var selectedText = getSelectedText();
  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = selectedText.trim();
    div.classList.add("highlight");
    replaceSelection(div);
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.highlight {
  background-color: #F5E283;
  display: inline;
}
```

```js
// Highlighter
// Selection: thx http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/copytoclipboard.shtml :)
function getSelectedText() {
  var selection = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  return selection
};
// Replacement: thx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362747/how-to-insert-an-element-at-selected-position-in-html-document/3363087#3363087
function replaceSelection(replacement) {
  var range, html;
  if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(replacement);
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    html = (replacement.nodeType == 3) ? replacement.data : replacement.outerHTML;
    range.pasteHTML(html);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  var selectedText = getSelectedText();
  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    console.log(selectedText);
    mark = document.createElement("mark");
    mark.innerHTML = selectedText.trim();
    mark.classList.add("highlight");
    replaceSelection(mark);
  }
});
```

```css
div.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Please, select this h1</h1>
  <p>and this text at the same time</p>
  
  <h1>Now, select <i>a part of this one</i></h1>
  <p>with this text</p>
  <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please give a better explanation of what you mean by "overrides the rest of the CSS and ruins the layout" ?

Comment: Hey :) I added a code snippet at the end of my post, I think it'll be clearer than my explanations. I meant to say that the highlighted text behaves like a new "block", regardless of the pre-existing tags and classes.

Comment: if you mean the loss of existing white-spaces, you should probably consider a way to preserve those spaces before doing the `mark.innerHTML = selectedText.trim();`

Comment: Yes, indeed (but it's not really my problem here). If we take the example of the snippet, I would like to be able to highlight the H1 **and** the text while keeping the H1 in its place. I guess that's more of a CSS issue than a JS problem.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The thing is you're replacing the entire content of the range selection, thus losing the html tags <h1> and <p> in the example. you need to find a way to go through each element inside the selection and create the highlight inside all of them. It's not trivial, I've been trying to play a bit with it as it's an interesting challenge but with limited success so far. if you want to take a look at what I've tried and try to improve on it - https://jsfiddle.net/FabioSG/59gsdfcx/5/

Comment: How didn't I think of it! Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try to find a solution based on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the issue. If you have styling on the h1 element, highlighting the text will remove the h1 styling as the highlighted element becomes a child of h1. Try this if you, for example, want to change the color:

```
h1, h1 div.highlight{
  color: red;
}
```

or

```
h1{
  color: red;
}

div.highlight{
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #F5E283;
  display: inline;
}
```

I also noticed an issue with the trim - if I select 'this ' in the string 'select this h1', the trailing space is trimmed and you get 'select thish1', which i prop not what you want.

Will it work without selectedText.trim()?

Cool feature so it gets fully working!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's a good idea, I'll look into it :)